# Overwritting Directory in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, directory, overwrite

I ran the following command to create a directory on the HDFS side

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir 20news-bydate/
```

but I got a message that the directory already exist. So how can I overwrite the directory?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove directory first

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -rm -R 20news-bydate/
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir 20news-bydate/
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you can try to remove first "hadoop fs -rmr" and then create....

as there are no ways pass parameter to owewrite it....